# How to measure the time of the device functions when they are called in kernel function

Tags: cuda

Hello in my kernel function i used 3 device function and i want to calculate the time taken by each device function.Is there any way to time the device functions time in kernel ? please kindly let me know Thank you

Comment: Perhaps this is one of few cases when there is no need to show the code? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the CUDA C Programming Guide:

```
clock_t clock();
long long int clock64();
```

> when executed in device code, returns the value of a per-multiprocessor counter that is
>   incremented every clock cycle. Sampling this counter at the beginning and at the end of
>   a kernel, taking the difference of the two samples, and recording the result per thread
>   provides a measure for each thread of the number of clock cycles taken by the device to
>   completely execute the thread, but not of the number of clock cycles the device actually
>   spent executing thread instructions. The former number is greater that the latter since
>   threads are time sliced.

This timing works pretty much Matlab's `tic` and `toc`. There is a *clock* sample in the CUDA SDK. Basically, it works like this

```
__global__ void max(..., int* time)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    clock_t start = clock(); 
    //device function call
    clock_t stop = clock();
    ...
    time[i] = (int)(stop - start);
}
```

Comment: do i need to add clock() for each device functions?

Comment: @ChaparalaAbhilash I have edited my post with a simple usage example.